# Calling GUI more than once

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I am developing a complex program in MATLAB R2013a to evaluate EEG and other data recorded from animals. I have a main GUI with a menu bar and two panels on which up to 16-16 axes can be shown. I created two GUIs with GUIDE. One is used to set the sampling rate, the number of recorded channels, etc., when I open a new data file. The other GUI is used to set how many graphs should be drawn in the main GUI, which recorded channel should be shown, is filtering necessary or not, etc. To set all these things takes about 400 controls (popuplists, checkboxes, etc.)

I call these GUIs several times from the main GUI. The first GUI keeps all changes that I made during the previous call, while the other GUI is reset to the initial state whenever I call it. Of course, I could store the values of these 400 controls, and somehow restore them to the previous state, but it would be very tedious.

Can somebody tell me why the two GUIs behave differently? In my view, it is not unusual that a GUI is called more than once from a program, and it also seems natural that the user only wants to change a few settings and not rewrite everything.

Comment: Without knowing how you set them up and call them, not really. May be useful: http://blogs.mathworks.com/videos/2010/12/10/how-to-save-and-restore-state-of-a-gui-in-matlab/

Comment: Looks like `<GUI1>_OpeningFcn()` (replace `<GUI1>` with the first GUI name) uses the `handles` to initialize its state, while `<GUI2>_OpeningFcn()` does this from scratch. Put a breakpoint in your GUI `.m` and see where this initialization takes place. With just prose and no code, I cannot help more.

Comment: You have to manually handle the `guidata`, which is prone for bugs. You can check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/589764/how-do-i-run-two-guis-in-matlab-in-parallel